# Upload entire directory via FTP in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp-client

I have successfully been able to upload single files to an FTP with this:

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile
```

Is there a way to upload an entire directory, such as this:

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFolder
```

Answer (score 2):

Never worked with FTP in VB.NET, but it seems there is no direct way to do it.

[Here is what people say about how it can be done](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/87abfbc9-5d98-4dc4-8975-a2b07e499325):

1. Traversal the local directory
2. Create the same directory structure in the FTP server.
3. Upload the file in each local directory.

Also [see here for same question answered (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252000/upload-a-folder-by-ftp). It confirms there is no built-in way. You would have to write some code or use 3rd party libraries.